# supervisord web interface doesnt allow external connections

Tags: nginx, supervisord

this is my supervisord web config, with no password

```
[inet_http_server]  
port=127.0.0.1:9001
;username=user         
;password=1234
```

and this is my nginx config for it

```
location /supervisor/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
```

If I access 127.0.0.1:9001 directly from within my server I get the info I need:

```
root@gosthost:~# curl 127.0.0.1:9001
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>Supervisor Status</title>
  <link href="stylesheets/supervisor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="images/icon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

 ... bla bla bla
</div>

<div class="clr" id="footer">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="http://supervisord.org">Supervisor</a> <span>3.1.3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    &copy; 2006-<span>2015</span> <strong><a href="http://agendaless.com/">Agendaless Consulting and Contributors</a></strong>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

but if I try to access it from outside world it gives me 404:

```
root@gosthost:~# curl http://46.101.172.89/supervisor/
<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 404.
<p>Message: Not Found.
</body>
```

But that's not nginx's native response. I can see that because nginx signs its own error responses, see below. This is typical nginx response

```
curl http://46.101.172.89/media/
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

so there is something wrong with supervisor. What could that be?

Answer (score 3):

little bit late, but I had the same problem and was trying everything and found solution

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
```

you missed `/` :)